# Event for synchronizing all controls using the same Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, behavior, attachedbehaviors

in my WPF application I have several forms with a multitude of input fields for the user. As it turns out not every user needs all fields depending on its companie's process therefore I have the new requirement to allow the user to hide fields depending on its own needs.

I was planning to use a Behavior for this which could be attached to basically every WPF-Control. The behavior would add a ContextMenu to each of the controls allowing to show/hide all of the available Fields. My current test project which seems to work nice has four DependencyProperties to make everything work:

1. string VisibilityGroupName:

This acts somehow as an Id for each field but is not unique in order to group multiple fields togther (eG a Label for a field caption to its corresponding TextBox). This string is currently also used as the name that the user sees in the ContextMenu.

2. Dictionary VisibilityDictionary:

This dictionary keeps track of all the visibility states of the fields. In my application I'm going to serialize this to XML in order to make the users decisions persistant.

3. bool AllowCustomVisibility:

This is just a flag in order to switch the whole funtionality off.

4. bool NotificationDummy:

This is where it gets interesting. Currently I abuse this property in conjunction with an ValueChanged-event to notify all the Controls that a state was changed so they can check if they are affected. While this works as expected I know that this is just a bad workaround because I don't know how the notification would be done correctly.

Does anybody have an idea how it is done correctly? I've marked the corresponding places in the code with TODOs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace CustomizableUserControlVisibility
{
    public class WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior : Behavior<DependencyObject>
    {
        #region Fields
        private Control _control = null;
        private ContextMenu _contextMenu;
        private bool _contextMenuIsBuilt = false;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public bool NotificationDummy
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(NotificationDummyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NotificationDummyProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NotificationDummyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NotificationDummy", typeof(bool), typeof(WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool AllowCustomVisibility
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowCustomVisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AllowCustomVisibilityProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowCustomVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AllowCustomVisibility", typeof(bool), typeof(WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public string VisibilityGroupName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(VisibilityGroupNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VisibilityGroupNameProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityGroupNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VisibilityGroupName", typeof(string), typeof(WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public Dictionary<string, bool> VisibilityDictionary
        {
            get { return (Dictionary<string, bool>)GetValue(VisibilityDictionaryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VisibilityDictionaryProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityDictionaryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VisibilityDictionary", typeof(Dictionary<string, bool>), typeof(WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(new Dictionary<string, bool>()));
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior()
        {
            // TODO: There should be a better way to notify other controls about state changes than this...
            var temp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior.NotificationDummyProperty, typeof(WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior));
            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp.AddValueChanged(this, OnNotificationDummyChanged);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Overrrides
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            if (this.AllowCustomVisibility == false)
            {
                return;
            }

            this._control = this.AssociatedObject as Control;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.VisibilityGroupName) && this._control != null)
            {
                if (this.VisibilityDictionary.ContainsKey(this.VisibilityGroupName))
                {
                    if (this.VisibilityDictionary[this.VisibilityGroupName])
                    {
                        this._control.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this._control.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.VisibilityDictionary.Add(this.VisibilityGroupName, this._control.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? true : false);
                }

                // Add a ContextMenu to the Control, but only if it does not already have one (TextBox brings its default ContextMenu for copy, cut and paste)
                if (this._control.ContextMenu == null && !(this._control is TextBox))
                {
                    this._contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                    ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(this._control, this._contextMenu);
                    this._control.ContextMenuOpening += (sender, e) => { ContextMenuOpening(e); };
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Event handling
        private void ContextMenuOpening(ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this._contextMenuIsBuilt == false)
            {
                this._contextMenu.Items.Clear();

                Dictionary<string, MenuItem> menuItems = new Dictionary<string, MenuItem>();

                foreach (string k in this.VisibilityDictionary.Keys)
                {
                    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem() { Header = k, Name = k, IsCheckable = true, StaysOpenOnClick = true };
                    menuItem.Click += MenuItem_Click;

                    menuItems.Add(k, menuItem);
                }

                var keyList = menuItems.Keys.ToList();
                keyList.Sort();

                foreach (string key in keyList)
                {
                    this._contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItems[key]);
                }

                this._contextMenuIsBuilt = true;
            }

            foreach (MenuItem mi in this._contextMenu.Items)
            {
                mi.IsChecked = this.VisibilityDictionary[mi.Name];
            }
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;

            if (mi != null && this.VisibilityDictionary != null && this.VisibilityDictionary.ContainsKey(mi.Name))
            {
                this.VisibilityDictionary[mi.Name] = mi.IsChecked;

                // TODO: There should be a better way to notify other controls about state changes than this...
                this.NotificationDummy = !NotificationDummy;
            }
        }

        private void OnNotificationDummyChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            // TODO: There should be a better way to notify other controls about state changes than this...
            if (this._control != null && this.VisibilityDictionary != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.VisibilityGroupName))
            {
                if (this.VisibilityDictionary.ContainsKey(this.VisibilityGroupName))
                {
                    if (this.VisibilityDictionary[this.VisibilityGroupName])
                    {
                        this._control.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this._control.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of any other ideas I decided to use a static Event which seems to solve my problem quite well and this approach at leasts saves me the NotificationDummy-DependencyProperty which I had to use in the first place.

If anybody is interested - here is my final solution:

namespace CustomizableUserControlVisibility
{
    public delegate void VisibilityChangedEventHandler(object visibilityDictionary);

```
public class WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior : Behavior<DependencyObject>
{
    #region Fields
    public static event VisibilityChangedEventHandler OnVisibilityChanged;

    private Control _control = null;
    private ContextMenu _contextMenu;
    private bool _contextMenuIsBuilt = false;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public bool AllowCustomVisibility
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowCustomVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowCustomVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowCustomVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AllowCustomVisibility", typeof(bool), typeof(WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public string VisibilityGroupName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(VisibilityGroupNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VisibilityGroupNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityGroupNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VisibilityGroupName", typeof(string), typeof(WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public Dictionary<string, bool> VisibilityDictionary
    {
        get { return (Dictionary<string, bool>)GetValue(VisibilityDictionaryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VisibilityDictionaryProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityDictionaryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VisibilityDictionary", typeof(Dictionary<string, bool>), typeof(WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(new Dictionary<string, bool>()));
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public WPFCustomVisibilityBehavior()
    {
        OnVisibilityChanged += VisibilityChanged;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Overrrides
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        if (this.AllowCustomVisibility == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        this._control = this.AssociatedObject as Control;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.VisibilityGroupName) && this._control != null)
        {
            if (this.VisibilityDictionary.ContainsKey(this.VisibilityGroupName))
            {
                if (this.VisibilityDictionary[this.VisibilityGroupName])
                {
                    this._control.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._control.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.VisibilityDictionary.Add(this.VisibilityGroupName, this._control.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? true : false);
            }
        }

        // Add a ContextMenu to the Control, but only if it does not already have one (TextBox brings its default ContextMenu for copy, cut and paste)
        if (this._control != null && this._control.ContextMenu == null && !(this._control is TextBox))
        {
            this._contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(this._control, this._contextMenu);
            this._control.ContextMenuOpening += (sender, e) => { ContextMenuOpening(e); };
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Event handling
    private void ContextMenuOpening(ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this._contextMenuIsBuilt == false)
        {
            // Clear Items just to be sure there is nothing in it...
            this._contextMenu.Items.Clear();

            // Create default items first
            MenuItem showAll = new MenuItem() { Header = "Show all optional fields", IsCheckable = false, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold };
            showAll.Click += MenuItem_ShowAll_Click;
            MenuItem hideAll = new MenuItem() { Header = "Hide all optional fields", IsCheckable = false, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold };
            hideAll.Click += MenuItem_HideAll_Click;

            // Create field items and sort them by name
            Dictionary<string, MenuItem> menuItems = new Dictionary<string, MenuItem>();
            foreach (string k in this.VisibilityDictionary.Keys)
            {
                MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem() { Header = k, Name = k, IsCheckable = true, StaysOpenOnClick = true };
                menuItem.Click += MenuItem_Click;

                menuItems.Add(k, menuItem);
            }
            var keyList = menuItems.Keys.ToList();
            keyList.Sort();

            // Now add default items followed by field items
            this._contextMenu.Items.Add(showAll);
            this._contextMenu.Items.Add(hideAll);
            this._contextMenu.Items.Add(new Separator());

            foreach (string key in keyList)
            {
                this._contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItems[key]);
            }

            this._contextMenuIsBuilt = true;
        }

        foreach (Object o in this._contextMenu.Items)
        {
            MenuItem mi = o as MenuItem;

            if (mi != null && mi.FontWeight != FontWeights.Bold)
            {
                mi.IsChecked = this.VisibilityDictionary[mi.Name];
            }
        }
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;

        if (mi != null && this.VisibilityDictionary != null && this.VisibilityDictionary.ContainsKey(mi.Name))
        {
            this.VisibilityDictionary[mi.Name] = mi.IsChecked;

            OnVisibilityChanged(this.VisibilityDictionary);
        }
    }

    private void MenuItem_HideAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> keys = this.VisibilityDictionary.Keys.ToList<string>();

        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            this.VisibilityDictionary[key] = false;
        }

        OnVisibilityChanged(this.VisibilityDictionary);
    }
    private void MenuItem_ShowAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> keys = this.VisibilityDictionary.Keys.ToList<string>();

        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            this.VisibilityDictionary[key] = true;
        }

        OnVisibilityChanged(this.VisibilityDictionary);
    }

    private void VisibilityChanged(object visibilityDictionary)
    {
        if (this._control != null && this.VisibilityDictionary != null && this.VisibilityDictionary == visibilityDictionary && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.VisibilityGroupName))
        {
            if (this.VisibilityDictionary.ContainsKey(this.VisibilityGroupName))
            {
                if (this.VisibilityDictionary[this.VisibilityGroupName])
                {
                    this._control.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._control.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}